# Multiple vars -> different string

Tags: php

When I get vars from an url I make a string. But the string must be different if the `var` exists or not on url. Here's an example:

I have two urls:

```
www.domain.com/list.php?cli=paris&resp=James&type=emp
www.domain.com/list.php?type=emp
```

I can get vars from first url with `$_GET`

```
$var = "HAVING ".$_GET['cli']." AND ".$_GET['resp']." AND ".$_GET['type'];
```

and

```
 $var = "HAVING paris and James and emp"
```

but on the second url I have `$var="HAVING AND AND emp"` because the first and the second vars are empty.

I can use multiple conditions for all of the vars (url can have 5 or 6 vars), but I think that there is a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: Argh! This not only smells of sql injection, this _stinks_!

Comment: I use it to extract info from Wordpress database, and make new tables with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Just use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and you don't have to check anything)

```
echo $var = "HAVING " . implode(" AND ", $_GET);
```

Output:

```
HAVING paris AND James AND emp 
HAVING emp
```

**EDIT:**

From your comment, this should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "HAVING ";
    $sep = "";

    foreach($_GET as $k => $v) {
        $str .= "$sep $k='$v'";
        $sep = " AND ";
    }

    echo $str;

?>
```

Output:

```
HAVING cli='paris' AND resp='James' AND type='emp'
HAVING type='emp'
```

Comment: I doubt this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @arkascha We will see what OP means/wants.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but i forget one thing and it doesn't works. Each var hava a pre-text. First output must be: "HAVING city='paris' AND name='James' AND type='emp' and second one must be "HAVING type='emp'. Sorry for mistake

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123. But with this code, string ends with an "AND" isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

use `isset()`..

e.g

```
$var1 = '';
if(isset($_GET['your_var']))
{
     $var1 = $_GET['your_var']
     //do your stuff here...
}
```